# How could I record how long I have been using vim this day?

Tags: vim, vim-plugin

I want to record how long I **actually** spent on coding per day, and as I basically do all my coding jobs through vim, I think the time I spent on using vim to edit files could represent the time I spent on coding.

So are there any vim plugins I could use to record the time I spent on vim?

Comment: let's say you only keep single vim session open.  8:00-9:00 you are working in vim, then you took 2 hours break without exiting vim. 11:00-12:00 you worked for 1 hour, then exit vim and went for lunch.  Assume  this is a whole days activity. How many hours as result do you expect to get?

Comment: Interesting, but off topic. You might find [this plugin of mine](https://github.com/AD7six/vim-activity-log) useful as a basis for something though.

Comment: You know you could just write it down. :-)

Comment: @AD7six, I think your plugin is really awesome, perhaps I could record my vim time using your plugin together with `crontab`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could check out [Wakatime](https://wakatime.com/) which will give you what you are looking for.  It shows time spend in the editor as well as on different filetypes/languages, which should help you differentiate between coding and assorted tasks.

Plugin installation instructions can be found [here](https://wakatime.com/help/plugins/vim)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not too sure about plugins, but perhaps you could write a wrapper script to execute vim. When you execute the script, it would first record the time stamp and then start vim with whatever parameters you passed in. When you exited vim, it would record the current time stamp and calculate the difference to determine how long you coded.  You could then integrate logging time tracking to files, etc, if interested in keeping a history.

Comment: I am trying to use `autocmd BufWinLeave ...`, howver, it seems that if I have used `:split` to edit two file, the event would be triggered twice as I would exit two files, so How could I trigger the event only when I completely exit vim?

Answer (score 0):

Try my [BufTimer](https://github.com/chrisbra/BufTimer) plugin. It let's you time your editing session.

Answer (score -1):

You don't necessarily need a plugin to get the information you want.

Assuming you're on *NIX, and you exit vim only at the end of your coding session, the easiest, most straightforward way to do this is with `time`:

```
$ time vim
```

[after coding, exit]

```
real    0m4.393s
user    0m0.072s
sys     0m0.013s
```

In this example, I spent 4.393 seconds coding.